# Logistic regression with cross validation cv.glmnet() not giving me auc values?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, cross-validation, glmnet

I have just started working with the glmnet package in R. I have s a dataset which has about 130,000 features and about 32000 rows of data. Here is the code to create the model

```
myModel = cv.glmnet(data.matrix(modelData), modelData$ACTION,
            family="binomial", type.measure="auc", nfolds=5, alpha=1)
```

My question is, is it possible to print the final auc for this model? Can someone provide any sample code?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you explain in detail exactly what  you mean by "this model"?

Comment: I was referring to the variable "myModel". When I print this variable the 3 columns that I see are Df, %Dev, Lambda. I was expecting to see a column for auc as opposed to %Dev

Comment: You have given no information about modelData and in particular about modelData$ACTION. I'm also surprised that you did not remove modelData$ACTION from the x argument.